# UITextView inputAccessoryView overlaps top of keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, inputaccessoryview

I have a pretty vanilla inputAccessoryView toolbar for some UITextView fields.  Previous, Next, and Done buttons.  I put them in a UIViewController class, and I assigned them to the UITextFields like this:

```
self.outPlayerOneTextField.inputAccessoryView = myAccessoryVc.view;
```

This worked great in iOS 7.  With iOS 8, it now overlaps the top of the keyboard, like so:

[image: accessory toolbar overlapping top of keyboard in ios8]

Any pointers on what changed?  Or perhaps wrapping it in a view controller wasn't a good thing to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing happen to me. The frame wasn't being set automatically by constraints for me. To fix it, I set the frame manually before setting the inputAccessoryView like this:

```
CGSize rect=[view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:CGSizeMake(0, 0)];
view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.width, rect.height);
```

Or if you use Objective C++ you can simplify it like this:

```
view.frame={{0,0},[view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:{0,0}]};
```